# Simple EventHandler/Provider using a variadic template and function pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, event-handling, function-pointers, variadic-templates

I'm trying to implement an EventProvider/Handler system to facilitate setting up a small application with reactive GUI for a school project. This particular approach to the broader Observer pattern is not mandated, but it seems like the most robust and lightweight - provided it's actually possible.

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>;
#include <algorithm>;

/// Provides a lightweight interface for implementing event-based behaviour.
template <class ...arg> class EventProvider
{
public:
    /// Defines a pointer to a function equipped to handle an event from this provider.
    typedef void( *EventHandler )(arg... arguments);

    EventProvider();
    virtual ~EventProvider();

    void Subscribe( EventHandler handler );
    void Unsubscibe( EventHandler handler );

    void Notify( arg... arguments );

protected:
    vector<EventHandler> _handlers;
};

template<class ...arg>
EventProvider<...arg>::EventProvider()
{}

template<class ...arg>
EventProvider<...arg>::~EventProvider()
{}

template<class ...arg>
inline void EventProvider<...arg>::Notify( arg... arguments )
{
    for ( auto handler : _handlers )
    {
        handler( arguments );
    }
}

template<class ...arg>
inline void EventProvider<...arg>::Subscribe( EventHandler handler )
{
    if ( find( _handlers.begin(), _handlers.end(), handler ) == _handlers.end() )
    {
        _handlers.push_back( handler );
    }
}

template<class ...arg>
inline void EventProvider<...arg>::Unsubscibe( EventHandler handler )
{
    _handlers.erase( remove( _handlers.begin(), _handlers.end(), handler ),     _handlers.end() );
}
```

What I have so far builds fine on its own, but if I actually try and include this header and use the code in other places, I get dozens of errors, all of them duplicates of...

> C2238 unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
>
> C2143 syntax error: missing ';' before '<'
>
> C4430 missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support
>   default-int

On the line where I've declared my vector of EventHandlers:

```
vector<EventHandler> _handlers;
```

> C2509 syntax error: '...'
>
> C3211 'EventProvider<>::**FunctionName**': explicit specialization is using partial specialization syntax, use template <> instead

On all of the function signatures in the implementation following the class template declaration, such as:

```
template<class ...arg>
EventProvider<...arg>::EventProvider()
{}
```

Comment: When presenting an error message, please explain to which line it applies.

Comment: Beneath each block of errors I've indicated which lines the errors are linked to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you should write

```
EventProvider<arg...>::
```

instead of

```
EventProvider<...arg>::
```

2) in

```
template<class ...arg>
inline void EventProvider<arg...>::Notify( arg... arguments )
{
    for ( auto handler : _handlers )
    {
        handler( arguments );
    }
}
```

`arguments` is a variadic parameter, so you have to unpack it with `...`; I suppose

```
 handler( arguments ... );
```

3) in

```
protected:
   vector<EventHandler> _handlers;
```

you have to use `std::` before `vector` (or add before `using namespace std;`)

4) there is no need of a semicolon after an `include` so, please,

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
```

instead of

```
#include <vector>;
#include <algorithm>;
```

Comment: Thanks!

Yikes, those semicolons after the includes and missing namespace were skeletons in the closet, I started this project in September when I had never written a line of C++.

The rest all makes sense. This is my first foray into variadic templates and you've been super helpful. Cheers.